# SSAS Performance: Multiple measures+no Dim vs one measure+DimType

Tags: performance, ssas, olap, fact

I am building a finance cube and trying to understand the best practice while designing my main fact table.

What do you think will be a better solution:

1. Have one column in the fact (amount) and have an additional field which will indicate the type of financial transaction (costs, income, tax, refund, etc).

T

```
 TransType        Amount         Date
  Costs            10            Aug-1
  Income           15            Aug-1
 Refunds            5            Aug-2
  Costs             5            Aug-2
```

2. "Pivot" the table to create several columns according to the type of the transaction.

---

```
Costs     Income       Refund       Date
10          15          NULL        Aug-1
5          NULL          5          Aug-2
```

Of course, the cube will follow whatever option is selected - several real measures vs several calculated measures which each one of the are based on one main measure while being sliced on a member from a "Transaction Type" dimension.

(in general all transaction types has the same number of rows)

thank you in advanced.
Oren.

Answer (score 0):

For a finance related cube, I believe it is much better to use account dimension functionality.
By using account dimension, you can add/remove accounts to the dimension without changing the structure of your model. Also if you use account dimension, time balance(aggregate function) functionality of the cube cube can help you a lot.

However SSAS account dimension has its own problems as well. For example, if you assign time balance to a formula or a hierachical parent, it is silently ignored and that is not documented as far as I know. So be ready to fix the calculations in the calculation script.

You can also use custom rollup member functionality to load your financial formulas.
In our case, we have 6000+ accounts, and the formulas can change without our control.
So having custom rollup member functionality helps a lot.

You need to be careful with solve orders(ratios..) etc, but that is as usual for any complicated/financial cube.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I think i mislead you by specifying the cube as a finance cube. According to what you wrote I think my module is not exactly a pure financial module. By "Account" do you mean the transaction type i mentioned above? or another dimension?

Comment: If the number of accounts/measures are fixed and there are too many of them. You can implement them as regular measures. The need for account dimension occurs mainly when you need to handle growing/shrinking measure count to avoid updating cube model all the time. Account dimension can handle time aggregations as well but that is secondary concern if you dont have too many measures.If you have just fixed list of measures as in your example, you can implement them as separate measures. That should work fine I believe.